# Oracle best practice

Tags: mysql, oracle, performance, plsql

I have to pull some incremental data and do some small and complex calculations after that. But in days passing by, the data grew large and after the 1st incremental stage, it started more time to insert and update large records.
So, what I did was:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 AS(SELECT (some_conditions) FROM SOME_TABLE);
CREATE TABLE T2 AS(SELECT (some_conditions) FROM T1);
DROP TABLE T1
RENAME T2 TO T
```

Is this a good practice in a production environment. It works very fast though.

Comment: If the code is working, it might be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Turing85 This seems to be purely example code, so no.

Comment: Should you have written that last statement as `RENAME T2 TO SOME_TABLE` ???

Comment: @APC Not necessary. The OP will need to confirm that, but as I understand, he need to regularly perform some kind of aggregation into table `T`.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux In which case presumably there's a missing `DROP TABLE T`.

Comment: "I have to pull some incremental data". This statement doesn't really contain enough detail for any judgement to be made.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd agree that DDL is pretty bad thing to do regularly but we need to be pragmatic.

I think if Tom Kyte (Oracle Guru) says it's ok then it's ok.

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: I've only skim read the referenced document, but I think the major bottleneck there was caused by the table having some index on it -- so slowing down dramatically the update process. This is not necessarily the case here.